# How to get page numbers of Index and bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, cross-referencing, indexing

Here is a skeleton .tex file for a book

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} % Put the bibliography in the ToC
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter}
\cite{darwin1859origin}
\index{Darwin}

The Index is on page ?. The bibliography is on page ?.

\backmatter

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Here is references.bib

```
@article{darwin1859origin,
  title={On the origin of species: facsimile of the first edition},
  author={Darwin, Charles},
  year={1859},
  publisher={LONDON: JOHN MURRAY, ALBEMARLE STREET.}
}
```

How can I get the page numbers for the Bibliography and Index? Obviously, they are somehow available, because the code that generates the table of contents knows what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not particularly robust in the case of the index, but it will work provided the index is not further customised and `tocbibbind` is not updated in some incompatible way.

It is hard to know where to insert the label in the case of the index, given the multiply-branching code `tocbibbind` provides. Obviously, you could test and patch appropriately, but that would still fail if things changed. So I've gone with `\thispagestyle` as the insertion trigger, which gets executed regardless of how the conditionals fall out. We add a one-time hook for this command to the `theindex` environment, since adding the label directly to the environment uses a hook which is either too early or too late.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{darwin1859origin,
  title={On the origin of species: facsimile of the first edition},
  author={Darwin, Charles},
  year={1859},
  publisher={LONDON: JOHN MURRAY, ALBEMARLE STREET.}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} % Put the bibliography in the ToC
\makeindex

\AddToHook{env/thebibitemlist/begin} {\label{ch:bibstartshere}}
\AddToHook{env/theindex/begin} {%
  \AddToHookNext{cmd/thispagestyle/after}{\label{ch:indexstartshere}}%
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter}
\cite{darwin1859origin}
\index{Darwin}

The Index is on page \pageref{ch:indexstartshere}. The bibliography is on page \pageref{ch:bibstartshere}.

\backmatter

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image: resulting croos-refs resolved]

Comment: Much thanks! I added the changes to my main book .tex file and the resulting PDF has the correct page numbers.